# Simple label display for Z in XYZ is not showing up

Tags: point, labeling, features, xyz

I have a DEM that I converted to XYZ point features.  I am trying to label each point using its Z attribute.  I had something similar work fine a few months ago, but now I am unable to display the Zs.   Here are the parameters I am using for labeling.

[image]

Comment: how about the attribute table: Are the z-values listed? And the Points are shown?

Comment: Z-values are listed and Z is selected.  The points themselves display fine.

Comment: can you label with x or y coordinates? Or what if you try with the expression editor. It gives a preview.

Comment: I tried to display X and Y with the same result. I will try the expression editor. Thanks.

Comment: I used the Expression Editor and entered @geometry = "Z" with the same result.  Any other ideas?

Comment: you should just enter `"z"` or `format_number("z")` or `to_string("z")`. The preview below gives you the result for each item.